# Java MongoDB connection pool

Tags: java, mongodb, pool

I am using Java with MongoDB. Here I am opening `MongoClient` in each method. I only need to open it once through out the class and close it once.

```
public class A
{
    public String name()
    {
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(host, port);
        DB db = mongo.getDB(database);
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(collection);

        BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("john", e.getName())
    }

    public String age()
    {
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(host, port);
        DB db = mongo.getDB(database);
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(collection);

        BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("age", e.getAge())
    }
}
```

Comment: this is just the replication of what i am working on. My main concern is about opening mongoclient only one time throughout the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Singleton pattern to guarantee only one instance of `MongoClient` class per application. Once you obtain the instance of `MongoClient`, you can perform your operations and don't need to explicitly manage operations like `MongoClient.close`,  as this object manages connection pooling automatically.

In your example, you can initialize the `MongoClient` in a static variable.