# MongoDB Connection Pooling Shutdown

Tags: mongodb, connection-pooling

We have mongodb as datastorage, and there is a MongoClient which we are using for connection pooling.

Question is whether to explicitly use the MongoClient.close to shutdown the connection pool or not.

Here's what I have explored on this so far.

The documentation for the close API says 
***Closes all resources associated with this instance, in particular any open network connections. Once called, this instance and any databases obtained from it can no longer be used.***

But when I referred other questions on this topic, it says ***you can perform your operations and don't need to explicitly manage operations like MongoClient.close, as this object manages connection pooling automatically.***

[Java MongoDB connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271707/java-mongodb-connection-pool)

Both of them are contradicting. If I were to follow the second, what will be the downsides of it?

Will the connections in the pool be closed when the mongoclient object is de-referenced from jvm?
or will the connections stay open for a particular period of time and then expire?
I would like to know what are the actual downsides of this approach. Any pointers on this is highly appreciated.

IMO, using close on server shut down seems to be the clean way to do it.
But I would like to get an expert opinion on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: There is no need to explicitly close the connection pool via API. Mongo driver takes care of it.